# $\oint_{C} z \sin(\frac{1}{z-1})$ where $C=\{z:|z|=2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I am considering the following integral

$$\oint_{C} z \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)\cdot dz$$

where the curve $C$ is defined as $C:=\{z:|z|=2\}$

First I considered doing the following

$z \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)=(z-1+1)\bigg(\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)\bigg)$

=$(z-1)\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)+\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)$

then the integral becomes

$$\oint_{C} (z-1)\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)+\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)\cdot dz$$

then by the resiude theorem it evaluates to

$$\oint_{C} (z-1)\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)+\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}\bigg)\cdot dz =0+2\pi i=2\pi i$$

is the solution correct?

Comment: Yep, it is...but can you justify each part? For example, why the first left integral in the last line is zero?

Comment: Because its residue will be zero relying on the fact

$(z-1)\sin(\frac{1}{z-1})=(z-1)\bigg(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{3!(z-1)^3}+\cdots   \bigg)$

we can see that $b_1=0$ (the coefficent of $\frac{1}{z-1}$)

Comment: Exactly...or the singularity at $\;z=1\;$ of that function is removable, as you in fact get a Taylor series about that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way: the only problematic point in the given domain is $\;z=1\;$ , so we develop a Laurent series for our function around this point (very similar to what you did!):

$$z\sin\frac1{z-1}=(z-1+1)\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{6(z-1)^3}+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=1-\frac1{6(z-1)^2}+\frac1{z-1}+\ldots\implies$$

The residue of our function at $\;z=1\;$ is $\;1\;$ , so by Cauchy (Residue) theorem your integral equals $\;2\pi i\cdot1=2\pi i\;$